# Migrating From Ember to React Page by Page Exploring Options

Tags: reactjs, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to move a big Ember v1.4.0 app to React. Instead of creating a new UI from scratch. I want to start building it in React my converting pages over slowly, essentially mixing React and Ember pages in one website.

***Goal:***
The above is my ultimate goal, but my first goal is is to create a single page in React that is called by Ember's router.

***What I have tried so far:***  I wanted to create a React component in a ./templates/myFirstTestPage.handlebars because, as I understand it, the router.js calls a template file. But I am unsuccessful creating a React component in the handlebars file. Firstly, I cannot use `<script>` to import React because `<script>` does not work in handlebars. Secondly, I believe the handlebars is parsing the React app in an incorrect way. Actually, I don't really understand how, and in what order, these frameworks do the rendering.

***Possible solutions (but I need implementation details):***

1. Somehow create a React component in the template folder with the .handlebars extension.
2. Refer to the url of a React app in the handlebars of an Ember app
3. Have the Ember router map the url to a jsx file. This solution seems really viable to me. I think to myself that surely the creators of Ember must have thought that people might want to have their Ember app refer to some regular html file. Hence, I hope someone might have some knowledge whether this is possible or not.
4. Somehow create my own router that maps urls to particular files. If its a React component, then I'd map it to my jsx file, if not, I let Ember's router take care of the mapping. I don't really know how to implement a url mapping thing though.

Comment: I don't think this will work as described in the possible solution. Ember compiles the template and renders the DOM using plain functions like `document.createElement()` and `Element.setAttribute()`. I think this was already true for the 1.4 version, which was [released 2014](https://blog.emberjs.com/2014/02/12/ember-1-4-0-and-ember-1-5-0-beta-released.html). I think you should create a component in Ember, which invokes the React app. Not sure if Ember already had the concept of components in February 2014. If I remember correctly there was something like `Ember.View` at that time.

Comment: @jelhan Actually there are components. Do you have more details about how to invoke the react app?

Comment: I don't have that much experience with React but I think it's about calling [`ReactDOM.render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) in that component. And to unmount it when the component gets destroyed of course.

Comment: @devdev sure we can't convince you to stick with Ember if it's already a large Ember app? ;-) The upgrade path in Ember has some bumps, but there are fewer than doing a full rewrite ... There are a few Ember-CLI add-ons that might be worth referencing as examples of what you'll want to explore (https://github.com/AltSchool/ember-cli-react and https://github.com/alexlafroscia/ember-react-components) But both assume a newer build pipeline than I think you probably have access to with your app right now

Comment: To be honest I doubt that you can gracefully migrate your ember app if it is already large. Unfortunately Ember has made it very hard to escape their ecosystem and using react as a view is probably not worth the effort. My advise is to stick with ember or rewrite the whole thing which is probably not economical.